# Why my MAUI control isn't visible but still interractive

Tags: xaml, maui, winui-3

We are currently working on a MAUI project, versioned on git. I got View containing a picker, but in my case the picker isn't visible. I can click and interact with it, and the logic is still here.
Furthermore, my colleagues have the right display (see below).

my colleagues' popup:

[image]

mine:

[image]
[image]
I haven't any more details to provide, because I don't even know were to find them. This [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10756) seems to be a similar case. Maybe it could help.

I've already uninstalled and reinstall VS22, all nuggets, et delete and cloned the git repo.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  There is no relevant detail in your post that we could use to help you

Comment: I want to see a screenshot, when the picker is expanded, and the items are visible in it. (The moment you interact with it.)

Comment: @Jason do not rush to close this question. Since the same repo runs differently on both machines, it is obviously not directly related to the code. And you cannot expect people to know which configuration in the OS is causing this issue. I suspect that the control is there, and is being rendered, and the problem is the native control coloring. This is why I ask for a screenshot of expanded control, If you want details, ask him for something specific.

Comment: @H.A.H. i edit and add the picture where the picker is expanded !

Comment: Oh and the selector in the picker is black, and thier is white. Seems like the theme color is applay in one way or another, but even if i change the theme color, nothing change in my side.

Comment: Please check my [last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78220841/5228202)  i have added a way to change color of the dropdown background and fourground (list of items when picker is expanded), do you mean that nothing changed even afteryou added the style to App.xaml (the one in Windows folder platform folder not maui one) ?

Comment: @Galaash Yes, it is the theme color. It is drawing for dark for some reason. Anyway, the CFun solution seems solid and easy workaround. Did you gave it a try?

Comment: @H.A.H. yes it works well ! But i need to do this for each US, label, etc i guess

Comment: @Galaash If that solution worked, accept that guy's answer, and if you have problems with other controls, just open new questions. I am surprised this was not put as "workaround" in the github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug from MAUI, as a workaround you can apply the below style in your "Platforms/Windows/App.xaml":

```xml
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxForeground" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
     <Color x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground">Black</Color>

     <Thickness x:Key="ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness">5</Thickness>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderBrush" Color="LightGray" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" />

     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxForegroundPointerOver" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxForegroundPressed" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownBackground" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemForeground" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Blue" />
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

- [Win UI reference](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.4-stable/controls/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml)
- [Related MAUI issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10756)

Comment: This is interesting. I had this idea that it will be related to the native control colors, but had no idea how it can be easily fixed.

Comment: Yes it is way simpler than Handlers but i believe it is somehow ugly and messy at the same time, but for a workaround it's ok.